# DatePicker How to disable minutes selection in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I have set datePickerMode: .time and gave max and min hour. But I want to disable minutes selection but didn't find any solution. I can give minutesInterval but I just want to show or choose only 00 for minutes. User must select only hour.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you want just selection of hour then use PickerView instead of datePicker and pass the hours array that contains value 00 to 23

Comment: Thx for your advice! I think I can use it.

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

What if you set the minuteInterval property of the date picker to 60?

If that doesn't work, and the only thing you're using the date picker to collect is hours, why not create a regular UIPickerView with hour values from 12 AM to 11 PM? (Or 0 AM to 23 PM, if you're using 24 hour time.)

Comment: Thx for your answer. When i set it to 60, it shows all minutes. And I already gave my hours range but it automatically shows minutes.

Comment: Simulate an hour picker using a custom UIPickerView  you then